# validating initialization variables in perl constructor using ref

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation, regex-group

I'm trying to apply a split function on a string only where 1 colon (:) exists using regular expressions. The problem is that while a colon could exist multiple times consecutively, I'm only interested in instances where a colon is not preceded or followed by another colon . Any other character could precede or follow the colon.

Example string:

```
my $example_string = "_Fruit|Apple:~Vegetable|Carrot:~fruitfunc|Package::User::Today:~datefunct|{~date}"
```

Expected result:

```
my @result_array = ["_Fruit|Apple","~Vegetable|Carrot","~fruitfunc|Package::User::Today","~datefunct|{~date}"];
```

What I've tried so far is a combination of negation and group regular expressions...one example that got me close:

1. Cuts off 1 value before and after colon

   ```
   my @result_array= split(/[^:][:][^:]/g, $example_string )

   @result_array = [
       '_targetfund|tes',
       'rowcountmax|10',
       'test|YE',
       'fruit|appl',
       'date|\'12/31/2016\''
   ];
   ```

I was playing around with https://regex101.com/, thought maybe there was a way to return $1 within the same regex or something which could be done recursively.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: sorry about the editing - result_array wouldn't format correctly

Comment: The problem is nobody knows it 2 colons is ok. What about 3 colons or 4 colons? If it is a standalone colon you need, just split using `(?<!:);(?!:)`

Comment: I repaired formatting but I am not sure what that is supposed to mean in the question? Can you clarify?

Comment: You could cheat and change `::` to a unique string not including any colons.  Then split, and then change the unique string in the substrings back to `::`

Comment: I've updated the description sln and zdim. Does it make more sense?

Comment: The question is very fine, I have no idea how I misunderstood it (in my answer).  The question I raised above is about the second chunk of displayed code -- I don't see what it is meant to show (and whether I missed the intention with "fixing" the formatting).

Comment: ah, my apologies - I didn't want to confuse people by leaving that block of code un-formatted, that's why I made the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe overkill, but i would use the

```
split /(?<!:):(?!:)/, $str;
```

demo

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

my $str = "_Fruit|Apple:~Vegetable|Carrot:~fruitfunc|Package::User::Today:~datefunct|{~date}";
my @wanted = ("_Fruit|Apple","~Vegetable|Carrot","~fruitfunc|Package::User::Today","~datefunct|{~date}");

my @arr = split /(?<!:):(?!:)/, $str;
is_deeply(\@arr, \@wanted);
done_testing(1);

#ok 1
#1..1
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Comment: @user3166881 yvw, enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use look-around assertions, i.e. split on semicolon not preceded nor followed by a semicolon:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::Deep;

my $example_string = "_Fruit|Apple:~Vegetable|Carrot:~fruitfunc|Package::User::Today:~datefunct|{~date}";

my $result_array = ["_Fruit|Apple","~Vegetable|Carrot","~fruitfunc|Package::User::Today","~datefunct|{~date}"];

cmp_deeply( [ split /(?<!:):(?!:)/, $example_string ], $result_array );
```

Comment: tried accepting your response as the answer as-well...doesn't look like it's possible.

Didn't know about Test::Deep though, thank you for teaching me something new

Answer (score 1):

This one should do the job : `:(?=~)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0nmUn/1)

Comment: Does not seem to split on a `:` not followed by a `~`.  While the example does not include that case, the text description seems to

Comment: No, it's a positive lookahead, it finds `:` followed by a `~`

Comment: Clarified the text, seems like the example gave the impression that a colon could only be followed by a ~, which is not always the case.